# kafka: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

```
String prefix = "B";

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-word-pattern");

    StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();

    //source
    KStream<String, String> stream = streamsBuilder.stream(SOURCE_TEST_TOPIC);

    //word processor
    KStream<String, String> wordProcessor = stream.flatMapValues(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(",")));

    //match
    KStream<String, String> matchProcessor =
            wordProcessor.filter((key, value) -> value.toUpperCase().startsWith(prefix));

    matchProcessor.to(WORD_TOPIC);

    Topology topology = streamsBuilder.build();

    try (KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(topology, properties)) {

        System.err.println("Stream is starting...");
        kafkaStreams.start();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            System.err.println("Stream is closing...");
            kafkaStreams.close();
        }));
    }
```

when I run this stream, this exception raised:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.(StreamsConfig.java:766)
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.(KafkaStreams.java:693)
> at
> kafkacustom.streams.KafkaStreamsExample.main(KafkaStreamsExample.java:42)

How can I fix it

Comment: What version of kafka-streams dependency are you using? Try a different one?

Comment: @Ayshan Is this issue resolved ? Even I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused because of libraries incompatibilites, check your `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients` and your `org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams` versions.

In my specific case `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:6.0.0-ccs`(confluent library) has removed this `TRACE` enum value from `RecordingLevel` Sensor inner class and I was using `org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:3.1.1` from open source version. So i just updated to the confluent version `6.0.0-css` and works

For further investigation on your side, click on the console log trace for the class `StreamsConfig`, should be line 794 and check the `Sensor` class if its inner class `RecordingLevel` has the `TRACE` enum value

For the "official" [repo](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/metrics/Sensor.java), it still reamins this enum value

Comment: You are hell right. After changing the kafka-stream version it worked for me.
My spring boot version is "2.4.5" and Kafka stream version is "2.6.0"